# How to get data from the edited cell in datagridview using c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview who's data source has been set using a list. My datagridview is editable. How can I get the edited cell new value?
I am a beginner in c# winform.

```
private void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{         Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id"].Value));
}
```

Using this code I get the previous value of the cell.

Comment: I haven't VS now but can you try something like this: `dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString()` ?

Comment: no it is still giving me the previous value and not the edited value.@AsfK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CellValueChanged` event.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        //do your checks to see RowIndex is not -1 and other good stuffs
            var row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var changedValue = (string) row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `CellEnter` event if you want to get the value as soon as  the cell is selected event and then to get the value of the selected cell just use:
 `datagridview1.CurrentCell.Value`if you want a String you can use `datagridview1.CurrentCell.Value.toString()`

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedcell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
}
```